# Why does the cube root of a polynomial in a finite field produce a different polynomial when re-cubed?

Tags: polynomials, roots, finite-fields, cryptography, sagemath

I'm using SageMath to try and determine whether the cube root of a polynomial exists in a finite field GF(2^8). Whilst raising the polynomial to the minus 3 does produce a root (that is in the finite field), re-cubing that polynomial produces an entirely different result, as follows:

`sage: cube = b^3 + b + 1
sage: cube_root = cube^(-3)
sage: cube_root
b^3 + b
sage: re_cube = cube_root^(3)
sage: re_cube
b^7 + b^4 + b
sage: cube_root_2 = re_cube^(-3)
sage: cube_root_2
b^3 + b`

Each of cube, cube_root, re_cube, and cube_root_2 have the parent:
`sage.rings.finite_rings.element_givaro.FiniteField_givaroElement object at 0x23428b788`

What might be causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cube roots are

$$ \sqrt[3]{x} = x^{1/3} $$

What you are computing is

$$ x^{-3} = \frac{1}{x^3} $$

(note that you might not be able to use the `^` operator in `sage` with rational number exponents; there is probably a "find an $n$-th root" function available, and maybe even a special function specifically for cube roots)

Comment: oh my god, that's really embarrassing, what an idiot... Thanks so much, and thanks for the nth root tips!

Comment: ah -- although, I still get a similar odd error even correctly using the nth_root function. The polynomial I was wanting to find the cube root for didn't produce an nth root, but to verify the function was doing what I think it was doing, I tried finding the root of a polynomial that I'd already cubed:

<code>
sage: c = b^3 + b + 1
sage: c^3
b^7 + b^6 + b^4 + b^3 + b^2 + 1
sage: cubed = c_a^3
sage: root = cubed.nth_root(3)
sage: root
b^7 + b^4 + b
</code>

Comment: @AgnesCameron: Cube roots aren't necessarily unique; if your field has a nontrivial third root of unity, then every number that has a cube root has three cube roots. And since $3 \mid 2^8 - 1$, $\mathbf{F}_{2^8}$ does have a nontrivial cube root of unity.

Comment: thanks so much! That's really helped!